# MYSQL, using function parameter or variable with JSON_TABLE results in ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database

Tags: mysql, json

Can I pass a function parameter or argument to MYSQL's JSON Functions. As is shown belo when I try it I get the someone what spurious message "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database ''". I am sure I am probably missing something obvious.
I can do this with Oracle. If I can't use a variable directly what are my options, the only one I can think of is a temporary table, which would probably be extremely expensive ?

```
    mysql> select count(*) CNT from JSON_TABLE( '[1,2,3]','$[*]' COLUMNS(I INTEGER PATH '$')) X;
--------------
select count(*) CNT from JSON_TABLE( '[1,2,3]','$[*]' COLUMNS(I INTEGER PATH '$')) X
--------------

+-----+
| CNT |
+-----+
|   3 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @X = '[4,5,6]';
--------------
set @X = '[4,5,6]'
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) CNT from JSON_TABLE( @X,'$[*]' COLUMNS(I INTEGER PATH '$')) X;
--------------
select count(*) CNT from JSON_TABLE( @X,'$[*]' COLUMNS(I INTEGER PATH '$')) X
--------------

+-----+
| CNT |
+-----+
|   3 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop function if exists COUNT_ROWS;
--------------
drop function if exists COUNT_ROWS
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION COUNT_ROWS(X JSON)
    -> returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
    -> begin
    ->   DECLARE CNT INTEGER;
    ->   SET CNT = (
    ->   select CNT = count(*)
    ->     from JSON_TABLE(
    ->           X,
    ->           '$[*]'
    ->           COLUMNS (
    ->             I INTEGER PATH '$'
    ->           )
    ->         ) X);
    ->    RETURN CNT;
    -> end;
    -> $$
--------------
CREATE FUNCTION COUNT_ROWS(X JSON)
returns INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
begin
  DECLARE CNT INTEGER;
  SET CNT = (
  select CNT = count(*)
    from JSON_TABLE(
          X,
          '$[*]'
          COLUMNS (
            I INTEGER PATH '$'
          )
        ) X);
   RETURN CNT;
end;
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> --
mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> select COUNT_ROWS('[1,2,3]');
--------------
select COUNT_ROWS('[1,2,3]')
--------------

ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database ''
```

Comment: This seems to be an bug. It probably doesn't work on Triggers and Events either. In Stored Procedures it works as expected. See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06a2f5972a424cc27a281111dda06852).

Comment: See bug report: [MySQL Bug #92976](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92976).

Comment: Thanks for filing it. I had pretty much come to the same conclusion last night after going back and forth between code that worked and code that didn't, but being a newbie to MySQL I  wasn't sure I wasn't missing something obvious